# Jmeter 5.4.3: Exception when file open is clicked: File>open

Tags: jmeter

Downloaded latest apache-jmeter-5.4.3
Click on File > Open

exception found in the command and logs:

> Uncaught Exception java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class
> com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.filechooser.DarkFilePaneUIBridge$DetailsTableModel
> (in unnamed module @0x327b636c) cannot access class
> sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder (in module java.desktop) because module
> java.desktop does not export sun.awt.shell to unnamed module
> @0x327b636c in thread Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main].
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class
> com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.filechooser.DarkFilePaneUIBridge$DetailsTableModel

java version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18 LTS
windows 11

Comment: workaround : jmeter-t.cmd used to run the .jmx file : 
Used 'Open with' to open abc.jmx > select other apps, and give 'jmeter-t.cmd' in the jmeter bin folder to open
--thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's a [bug in JMeter](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=482318) use one of the following workarounds:

1. Change "Look and Feel" to something which doesn't contain `Darklaf`

   [image]
2. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   jmeter.laf=CrossPlatform
   ```
3. Downgrade to [Java 8](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/)
4. Try [Nightly Build](https://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html) of JMeter
5. Add `--add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.shell=ALL-UNNAMED` to [this line](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/bin/jmeter.bat#L112) of `jmeter.bat` startup script

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved in current JMeter release: 5.5

https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi

Thanks